# Async Drillup with highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

I have highmaps chart with drilldowns. All the data are loaded async from the server. I also have some filters that can be applied on the data (in which case the data is loaded again from the server with filters and series updated). 
This all works well except in one use case: if you drill down and then apply some filters this changes the data in drilldown. If you now drill up, the data should be changed in top level as well.

I tried handling drill up event to adjust the data, this works ok but has a caveat. While my actual data is being loaded async from the server, the chart actually shows old top series data which is not really good any more. Once my real data is loaded and I update the series the chart is good again.

Is there some kind of async drillup (e.g. chart.addDrillupSeries/applyDrillup) mechanism similar to async drilldown mechanism?

Comment: Do you have any current code? How do you replace the top series currently, even though there is a delay?

Comment: Hi @mdmilic, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor?